# Listening for "owner change" events for the clipboard in gtk2hs. How to set up?

Tags: haskell, gtk2hs

Using Gtk2Hs, I want to set up a callback to listen for "Owner change" events for the clipboard.

I can find out if this is supported by the X server by querying:

```
display <- fmap fromJust displayGetDefault
canBeNotified <- displayRequestSelectionNotification display selectionPrimary
```

It should be straight forward to do like [this](https://github.com/bstpierre/gtk-examples/blob/master/c/clipboard_watch.c) in C:

```
GtkClipboard* clipboard = gtk_clipboard_get(GDK_SELECTION_PRIMARY);
g_signal_connect(clipboard, "owner-change",
G_CALLBACK(handle_owner_change), NULL);
```

I see that callbacks in Gtk2Hs are set up like this:

```
<widget> `on` <event> $ <action>
```

Problems

- I cannot find any `OwnerChangeEvent`. [Graphics.UI.Gtk.Gdk.EventM](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3-0.13.4/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Gdk-EventM.html) does only provide functions of type `EventM` to query the owner change events.
- `on` from [System.Glib.Signals](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/glib-0.11.2/docs/System-Glib-Signals.html) <s>needs an associated widget</s> takes any object and an event associated to that object (`on :: object -> Signal object callback -> callback -> IO (ConnectId object`). If I have understood X correctly, it should not be necessary to have a window to listen for this event.

Either I have misunderstood how to wrap this together, or I have reached upon a yet not implemented part of gtk in Gtk2Hs.

I therefore looked at the definition of `keyPressEvent` which looks like this:

```
keyPressEvent :: WidgetClass self => Signal self (EventM EKey Bool)
keyPressEvent = Signal (eventM "key_press_event" [KeyPressMask])
```

So, I tested by simply adding a definition for `ownerChangeEvent` in gtk like `keyPressEvent`, but subsituted `"key_press_event"` for `"owner_change_event"`.

That did not work as I got a runtime error about not finding the event. Naturally.

Any ideas on how to properly listen for "owner change" events in gtk if possible?

Comment: Re: "`on` needs an associated widget": The C code seems to use the equivlalent of the `Graphics.UI.Gtk.General.Clipboard.Clipboard` type as the originating object of the `owner-change` signal. Maybe your problem was looking for an `"owner_changed_event"` on `Widget` insted of `Clipboard`?

Comment: You are right, `on` actually takes any object but the constraint imposed is that the event needs to belong to the same object. However, there still isn't (I cannot find) any Signal with a ClipboardClass constraint (`ClipboardClass class => Signal class callback`).

Comment: Right, but you could try adding your new signal to `ClipboardClass` instead of `WidgetClass` and see if that works.

Comment: I tried, but the signal is construct with a function called eventM which has a `WidgetClass` constraint. And there's probably a good reason for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that this is not implemented at the moment. Adding it shouldn't be too involved, and might be a fun project if you're looking to get into gtk2hs development. You'll want to add a new constructor to the [`Event`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.13.4/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Gdk-Events.html#t:Event) type, together with a descriptive type alias like `type EventOwnerChange = Event`. You will need to extend [`marshalEvent`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.13.4/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Gdk-Events.html#v:marshalEvent) to handle this new kind of event, and there may be an unmarshalEvent hanging around though I can't remember.

Once that's all done, it should be pretty easy to connect to the appropriate signal using the `connect_*` family of functions (which are for gtk2hs internal use only and therefore are not exposed in the API). From the documentation for the [owner-change](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Clipboards.html#GtkClipboard-owner-change) event, you will probably need to use something like `Signal (connect_OBJECT__NONE "owner-change")`.

It may also be necessary to add to the `EventMask` type, though I'm not confident -- test it out and see.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it. It will require quite some reading though, as I am still both a haskell beginner and new to gtk. So wish me luck!